# Regular expression to allow alphabets and onle one occurrence of select special characters

Tags: java, regex

I need regex for name field. Name can only be alphabets. The other requirements for the name field are that it can contain
but it is not necessary to have, any one of these characters: an apostrophe (') or a pound (#) or a hyphen (-)
I have this so far

```
 [\\w]*[\'#-]?
```

This checks the special character but only at the end of the string.
For example

```
JohnO'Connell -> returns false -> should return true

JohnOConnell' -> returns true -> expected behavior
JohnOConnell# -> returns true -> expected behavior
JohnOConnell- -> returns true -> expected behavior
JohnOConnell-# -> returns false -> expected behavior
```

How does this have to be updated to ?

Thanks

Comment: Only single apostrophe, pound or a hyphen is allowed? Is it possible to have 2 apostrophes?

Comment: No it is not possible to have any 2 of the special characters. Not even repeats of the special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+['#-]?[a-zA-Z]*$
```

Just making the `'`, `#`, `-` is optional at the middle.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this and if the special characters are added to the end of the string then it breaks or returns false. The special characters can be anywhere in the string.

Comment: @user1860447 your last comment contradicts with the example on your question description! Not sure what you exactly looking for. Try changing `+` into `*` from above regex. But your own risk!

Comment: Sorry. That was my error. Copy and Paste culprit. I will edit the question.

Comment: I ended up implementing it like this :   ^[a-zA-Z]*['#-]?[a-zA-Z]*\$

Answer (score 0):

This one allow any unicode letter:

```
^\pL+['#-]?\pL+$
```